# Python EAN-13 Barcode generator script overflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, computer-science

I have a script that generates all possible EAN-13 barcodes. Problem is that it doesn't run because I believe I'm getting arithmetic overflows. Is it possible to optimize this so I can get all the possible values? A EAN-13 barcode looks like *0000000000001*,*1000000000000* or *0293401925347*, etc. Total combinations should be 10^13:

```
for k in range(13, 14):
    for number in list(product(range(13), repeat=k)):
        barcode = "".join(map(str, number))
        print(barcode)
```

Comment: Cannot EAN13s have check digits as well ("X") as the last character?

Comment: dont understand your question.

Comment: Well your algorithm only accounts for numbers. (ISBNs for examples which are EAN13s, can have "X"'s as the last character (its checkdigit) when the number itself happens to be a zero. It was just a thought for your alg:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

Comment: ah okay understood. i'm only considering numbers for 13 digits for now. and i'm already experiencing issues. if you can provide an algo for both that'd be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code. Let's look at the differences to

```
from itertools import product

k = 13

for number in product(range(10), repeat = k):
    barcode = "".join(map(str, number))
    print(barcode)
```

1) Your loop for `k` is in the `range(13, 14)`. This is the same as `k=13`
2) Your `range(13)` is wrong, since we only want to join digits `0` to `9`
3) You wrote `list(product()`. This creates a list of 10^13 numbers, which takes a lot of space and time to produce. Iterate instead over the `itertools` object directly to avoid this. If you want to know more about iterators and generators, please have a look at this [introduction to generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Tldr: Advantage: they produce the next element only, when asked, saving memory space and computing time for elements, we don't use. Disadvantage: They exhaust, i.e. once a generated element has been used, the generator can't access it any more.

Comment: Okay thanks, but if you set K= 3 you tool would just iterate 1->999. However, I need it to include values like 001, 010, 100, 101, 110, 011 for that reason i did the list.

Comment: I don't understand your question. My output gives me for k = 3 `000
001
002
003
004...`

Comment: sorry i was confused. :O my math was totally way off.